# How to allow scroll directions across different manager field?

Tags: blackberry, field

Let me give an example. This code works within a manager:

```java
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {
        int focusIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();

        while (dy > 0) {
            if (focusIndex + columnwidth.length >= getFieldCount()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex + columnwidth.length);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy--;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dy < 0) {
            if (focusIndex - columnwidth.length < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex - columnwidth.length);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy++;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dx > 0) {
            focusIndex++;
            if (focusIndex >= getFieldCount()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dx--;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dx < 0) {
            focusIndex--;
            if (focusIndex < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
}
```

Now my screen adds the 3 different managers like this.

```java
add(new Custom_TopField(this, 0, -1, "", 1, 1));
add(new Custom_BottomField(this, 0));
add(new Custom_HeaderField(Config_GlobalFunction.latest));
```

all also `extends Manager` but when i go down, it is going left instead of going to the bottom.

Comment: total number fields of a row -> 4

Comment: where did you put the `navigationMovement()` method you showed above?  did you put it in all three classes: `Custom_TopField`, `Custom_BottomField`, and `Custom_HeaderField`?

Comment: nop, there was three difference classes. I tried to put it works only inside of its class but cannot across classes. For example, first class, I have 3 fields horizontally. when I move left right it work logical but when i move up down, it will still move left and right by logic, it should out of this class and focus on another class which is forth field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but this solution is not practical at all. I created all the class within a  java class. So, the class cannot be reuse.